# Websocket stability issue

Tags: websocket, ip, stability

I am testing `Websocket` connectivity over `VPN`. I see that it is much more stable when using the host name to connect than using the IP address alone.

Could somebody suggest any possible reason for this?

Also, I could nowhere find the nature of Websocket frames, if they are transmitted sequentially or in a random fashion?

Comment: WebSocket frames are handled sequentially. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455  There is nothing in the WebSocket standard that would make the connection any more or less stable when using a domain name over an IP address, and the nature of the TCP/IP protocol suite would make using a specific IP address more reliable, but only just barely, only because it passes DNS checks.

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket relies on TCP which orders the data for you.  TCP gives you the abstraction of an ordered stream.

WebSocket can either use hostnames or IP addresses.  Not quite sure what you mean by "much more stable", but if you are experiencing connectivity issues, it could be your DNS service... or it could be the implementation of WebSocket that you are using.